# Added CSS file and am seeing massive slowdown in Chrome

Tags: css

I added jquery ui 1.8.21 redmond css file to my project and am noticing severe slowness in Chrome. Of course this probably isn't related to the jQuery file itself, so I suspect one or more of those rules are interfering with my current page somehow (not really sure how, I don't see a selector that would match any on page elements).

What are some ways I can go about figuring out what the root cause of this really is? I don't see much useful info from Chrome developer tools, but I may just not know about some cool feature.

Answer (score 1):

Try using PageSpeed plugin for Chrome Developer tools. Maybe it can tell you where the problem is